# Помогите сделать кнопку hamburger

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```js
var headerList = document.querySelector('.header-list'); 
var bt = document.querySelector('.fa-bar'); 

bt.addEventListener('click', function(){
    headerList.classList.toggle('bta');
});
```

```css
.header-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end; }
  .header-list__item {
    margin-left: 40px; }
  .header-list:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; }
  .header-list__link {
    color: #292929;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
    .header-list__link:hover {
      color: #eb5074;
      text-decoration: none; }

.bt {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 13px);
  left: calc(50% - 13px);
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: none; }

.bta {
  display: block; }
```

```html
<header class="header">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-baseline lini no-gutters">
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12">
    <div class="logo">
     <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12">
    <ul class="header-list">
     <li class="header-list__item"><a href="#" class="header-list__link">главная</a></li>
     <li class="header-list__item"><a href="#" class="header-list__link">о производителе</a></li>
     <li class="header-list__item"><a href="#" class="header-list__link">продукты</a></li>
     <li class="header-list__item"><a href="#" class="header-list__link">проекты</a></li>
     <li class="header-list__item"><a href="#" class="header-list__link">контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="bt">
     <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: А в чём проблема-то? Вы код в вопросе доведите до рабочего вида. И уточните, что такое гамбургер в вашем понятии. Или ссылку дайте на описание.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держите гамбургер.

```js
let $hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger'),
  $menu = document.getElementById('menu');

$hamburger.addEventListener('click', function () {
  $hamburger.classList.toggle('active');
  if ($hamburger.classList.contains('active')) {
    $menu.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    $menu.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
#hamburger div{width:25px;padding-top:4px;border-bottom:3px solid #000;transition:all.3s}
#hamburger.active div{margin-left:4px}
#hamburger.active div:nth-child(1){transform:rotate(45deg);transform-origin:top left}
#hamburger.active div:nth-child(2){opacity:0}
#hamburger.active div:nth-child(3){transform:rotate(-45deg);transform-origin:bottom left;
margin:1px 0 0 2px}
#menu{display:none}
```

```html
<div id="hamburger" data-target="menu">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Примастырите к своему коду, думаю, сами)

Comment: Большая просьба к минусующим, давать объективный коммент к своему действию. Когда минусуются рабочие ответы, это немного непонятно.

Comment: спасибо, как всегда мне поручают самое трудное